# Class php_com_dotnet is missing in php

Tags: php, com

So I am using the call php_com_dotnet in my code:

```
$word = new COM("word.application");

// Hide MS Word application window
$word->Visible = 0;

//Create new document
$word->Documents->Add();

// Define page margins
$word->Selection->PageSetup->LeftMargin = '2';
$word->Selection->PageSetup->RightMargin = '2';

// Define font settings
$word->Selection->Font->Name = 'Arial';
$word->Selection->Font->Size = 10;

// Add text
$word->Selection->TypeText("TEXT!");

// Save document
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "word");
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($filename);

// Close and quit
$word->quit();
unset($word);

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

// Send file to browser
readfile($filename);
unlink($filename);
```

and I got his error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/nordin/save.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/nordin/save.php on line 6

so I looked around I added this to my php.ini file:

```
 [COM_DOT_NET]
 ;extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

 enable_dl = On
 ; extension_dir = "ext"
```

and it still doesn't work, what am I doing wrong? please help!

EDIT

my files are on a sftp server and I get error's like this:

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: and where do you require/include the file that declares the class?

Comment: The `;` at the beginning of a line in php.ini means _this line is a comment_, duh!

Comment: @04FS oh didn't know that. thank you.

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Comment: @Machavity windows 10

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused then. Under Windows you should be getting Windows paths in the error message, not Unix paths

Comment: @Machavity I do this for error repors   ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);  error_reporting(E_ALL); does that matter? and my file are on a sftp server

Comment: It's starting to sound like you are writing your code on Windows but running your code on Linux. I don't think you'll be able to use the COM object if that is the case.

Comment: IF this is true than what can I use instead of the com class?

Answer (score 1):

The semi-colon before the extension is a comment and means that extension is not enabled. To enable it you must remove that semi-colon:

```
;extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

becomes

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

You may need to restart IIS after making this change.

Comment: thank you just changed, but it didn't work, could my problem be the server itself.

Comment: The OP is confused. `Class 'COM' not found in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/nordin/save.php` indicates a Unix environment, but `php_com_dotnet.dll` is for Windows

Comment: @Machavity no I am on windows and I even have the file php_com_dotnet.dll

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is:

```
extension=com_dotnet
```

Comment: Thanks it works on php 7.4.25